# to compile a library from multiple sources

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I want to build a library from multiple source files, like a1.cpp a2.cpp. I used the following command, 'g++ -o libcode -c a1.cpp a2.cpp'. However, error pop up "cannot specify -o with -c or -S with multiple files".

In general, how should I build such lib from multiple sources? thanks...

Comment: To add to what leonbloy answered, combining `-o` with `-c` doesn't make sense. `-c` says "Don't produce an output, just make the binary objects", while `-o` says "This is the name of the output"

Comment: Using `-o` and `-c` together makes perfect sense, I do it all the time. The `-c` flag means "compile, but don't link". What version of g++ are you using?

Comment: `-o` with `-c` would (supposedly) mean the name of the object file. But that would not make sense if there are several source files (and hence several object files).

Comment: @leonbloy: you're right, I misparsed the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first compile your source files to objects files (`*.o`), and then invoke the **[ar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar)** command to build the library. In your example:

```
   g++ -c a1.cpp a2.cpp
   ar rcs libcode.a a1.o a2.o
```

This would build a static library, you can also create a dynamic one.

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_79.html

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/static-libraries.html